# Adding to array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following : `var navitems = new Button[5]` .. Now how do I add to the array? I keep getting a null reference at runtime. To add, i am doing the following in a for loop :

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    button b=new Button();
    navitems[i]=b;
}
```

Note : No need to worry about how the buttons will be formatted, I already have that covered.

Fine here is the actual code, didn't wanna give too much away..

```
var groups = Connection.Groups();

            var navitems = new TileNavItem[5];

            for (int i=0;i > groups.Count; i++)
            {
                TileNavItem item = new TileNavItem()
                {
                    Caption = groups[i].Description,
                    TileText = "Dashboards"
                };

                navitems[i] = item;
            }
```

I'm using devexpress trial and i would like to create my tilenavpane items dynamically.. If i do the following `navitems.Items.AddRange(new TileNavItem[] { item1, item2, item3 });`, it works great so I figured I could easily implement this dynamically.

Comment: `navitems[5]` does not exist, you have only four items, namely `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` You want your loop to go until `i<5`. You could have seen this yourself immediately if you had debugged your code.

Comment: this is not the part causing null reference exception.

Comment: I'd expect that to give an array index out of bounds exception, as you're trying to put 6 elements into a 5-element array... but if you're getting an NRE, that suggests you haven't *actually* assigned a non-null value to `navitems`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @oerkelens: That won't lead to an NRE though.

Comment: @JonSkeet true, I have to admit I assumed "getting a null reference" referred to an index out of bound exeption. Possibly the null reference exception happens before this code is called.

Comment: You have to make your code snippet complete by showing the declaration of `navitems`. Most likely you've got the same declaration in multiple places.

Comment: It's all mentioned in documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays

Comment: in addition to first comment, don't use `i < 6` because its error prone and its not tied with your array. use `i < navitems.Length` instead.

Comment: First of all, as you try to add six items to the array, you should be making your array large enough to contain six items: `var navitems = new Button[6];`. However, this does not seems to be the only problem, because a too small array gives you an `IndexOutOfRangeException` and not a `NullReferenceException`. Can you show the stack trace and explain in what line the NRE occurs?

Comment: With the exception of array out of bounds this should work: does the null reference relate to the actual array, or maybe it is another problem.

Comment: We need an [mcve] because this code does will not produce the error from the question. It does cause another error.

Comment: I have edited my question .. please take a look

Comment: `i=0;i > groups.Count` ? Really?

Comment: You will get an error if `groups.Count` is greater than 5.

Comment: Check your `groups` collection. I bet one or more of them is `null`

Comment: unless `groups.Count` is negative, this `for (int i=0;i > groups.Count; i++)` will never run, since the first value for `i` is zero.

Comment: the for loop is never entered because `i > groups.Count` should be `i < groups.Count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your array the correct size for your items, and be more careful with your for-loops:

```
var groups = Connection.Groups();
var navitems = new TileNavItem[groups.Count];
for (int i=0; i < groups.Count; i++)
{
    navitems[i] = new TileNavItem
    {
        Caption = groups[i].Description,
        TileText = "Dashboards
    };
}
```

Note that I also removed a superfluous variable.

This code may still fail if `Connection.Groups` can return `null` items.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. unfortunately not much luck, im still getting a null reference

Comment: Oh my word ! Thanks!!! Looks like i was checking whether "i" is greater than the count of groups ... Total noob mistake.. thank you, it works now

Answer (score 0):

You need increase array size

```
var navitems = new Button[6]
```

of decrease loop

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    button b=new Button();
    navitems[i]=b;
}
```

Comment: Please, use `navitems.Length` instead of magic numbers 5 or 6.

Comment: I updated my question, have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `TileNavItem`(s) to the collection at run time after adding the initial 5 (not tested):

```
TileNavItem item6 = new TileNavItem() { TileText = "Item 6" };

navitems.Items.Add(item6);
```

https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/18127/Controls-and-Libraries/Navigation-Controls/TileNav-Pane/How-to-Create-and-Customize-the-TileNavPane-Control-in-Code

Comment: That was the first thing i tried